# Invalid or unexpected token at new Function of Enumerable using linqjs

Tags: linq.js

I want to return an object using Enumerable of linqjs. But this code gives an error "Invalid or unexpected token". When I check the same condition using if condition in `forEach` then it is working perfectly. But what's problem with `Enumerable`?

Using Linqjs

```
var checkAddressForUpdate = Enumerable.From($scope.companyAddresslist).Where("$.Address === '" + $scope.ad_CompanyAddress.Address + "' && $.SlNo !== " + $scope.ad_CompanyAddress.SlNo).FirstOrDefault();
```

Using If Condition

```
var checkAddressForUpdate;
            angular.forEach($scope.companyAddresslist, function (comAddress) {
                if (comAddress.Address == $scope.ad_CompanyAddress.Address && comAddress.SlNo != $scope.ad_CompanyAddress.SlNo) {
                    checkAddressForUpdate = comAddress;
                }
            });
```

Error in console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqZJt.png)

Comment: Why is the operator `!==` in the `Enumerable` and `!=` in the `forEach`? What is the type of `$.SlNo`?

Comment: I used !== in the Enumerable and != in the forEach for testing. You can use != operator for both Enumerable and forEach it give same error

Comment: What is the type of `SlNo`?